# "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list " Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, nightwatch

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
```

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I'm trying to debug the Nightwatch code. Can anyone help me in resolving this issue

Comment: I also wanna know how does debugging work in Nightwatch.

The same code works while I'm executing in Non-Debugging mode.

Comment: Personally I've never heard of nightwatch, but the first thing that sticks out is that you're using `"..."` to encapsulate a string that has unescaped `"` *inside* of it. That seems off to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `debug` parameter inside package.json like this:

```
"debug": "node --inspect-brk node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch"
```

and run - `npm run debug` in the terminal